# Implement scroll and updown functionality to Increment Date on maskedTextBox c# winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker, maskedtextbox

I have created a MaksedTextBox which accepts and validates UK date format. This takes user input from both a dateTimePicker Calender and the Masked TextBox itself by typing. The reason for this approach over solely using a `DateTimePicker` control on its own was that I was experiencing a huge amounts of bugs using the `Format` property, and my `DateTimePicker` control would destroy the native control and recreate it again, no longer remembering that the day was entered.

Now I want to be able to tab and scroll using the mouse into my `maskedTextBox` and using the Arrow keys or and scroll using the mouse, increment or decrement the days, months and years fields.  I know It would be easier to use the `DateTimePicker` but for its flaws I cannot for this application.

```
  private  void maskedTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            int currentNumber = Convert.ToInt32(maskedTextBox1.Text);
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
            {

                maskedTextBox1.Text = (currentNumber + 1).ToString();
            }
            else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down)
            {
                maskedTextBox1.Text = (currentNumber - 1).ToString();
            }

            toolTip1.Hide(maskedTextBox1);
        }
```

This is what I have tried however to no avail

Comment: you could catch the keydown event on the maskedtextbox/datetimepicker and set `e.handled = true`

Comment: I've tried that but Doesnt seem to work, I think maye due to my Validation